# How do I make this JavaScript work to trigger a sound file?

Tags: javascript, audio

I put this javascript in the head tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
```

I put the following code in a div half way down the page:

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playSound('singing-bowl.wav');"><img id="bowl"       
src="pics/singing-bowl.gif" height="119" width="157" /></a>
```

It's not working.  I don't know javascript very well, but this supposedly works from the sources I copied it from.  I've tried it using both an mp3 version and a wav version.  Neither is working for me.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function playSound(val)
{
   var sound = new Audio(val);
   sound.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
     // your call back function
       // for example to play the sound
       sound.play();
   }, false);
}
```

To be more Efficient

```
var sound =null;
var isReady = false;
window.onload = function()
{
   sound = new Audio('singing-bowl.wav');
   sound.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
        isReady = true;
   }, false);

}
function playSound()
{
    if(isReady)
    sound.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have requirements to support old browser i would suggest you use html5,

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

And please pay attention that different browsers support different types

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp